# Laravel MySql join table to get a tree folder estructure

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, join, tree

I'm trying to create a query in Laravel to build a tree structure between 'projects', 'user' and 'messages'. I've achieved to get results when the a project has unread messages, but when the project has readed messages I also need to keep the project data in the tree list, so I have to list always the projects with readed or unread messages. This is my query but I'm not and expert in MySQL.

```
$query = DB::table('projects')
        ->select(DB::raw('
            projects.id,
            COUNT(DISTINCT messages.id) as unread_messages
        '))
        ->join('messages', 'messages.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->join('participants', 'messages.thread_id', '=', 'participants.thread_id')
        ->whereRaw('(participants.last_read IS NULL OR participants.last_read < messages.updated_at)')
        ->where('participants.user_id', $user->id)
        ->where('messages.user_id', '<>', $user->id);
```

This is what I get when I have unread messages:

```
[{"id":1,"unread_messages":5}]
```

And this is what I get when I have ALL messages readed in the project:

```
[{"id":null,"unread_messages":0}]
```

The project's id disssaper...

Please, somebody can help me and save my weekend??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using Models to do this?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yes, is a complex query and when I use eloquent models to get unread messages the query is very recursive to the DB, or maybe I'm wrong... But I think is healthy to obtain this results in one or two queries.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see your updates and was misunderstanding what you were trying to do at first

Comment: Also the only way to compare and get the unread messages, is comparing the "participants.last_read" column with the "messages.updated_at" column.